# Multicolum layout in Chrome being weird

Tags: css, google-chrome, multicol

While building a mega menu using CSS-multicolumn to fill the flyout nicely with content boxes, I hit a snag: Chrome insists on arranging the blocks weirdly. Please open this fiddle in Chrome and in Firefox to see what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/061ar2x6/4/

Firefox does it right (i.e. the way I want it):

[ 1     ] [ 2     ] [ 3     ] [ 4     ]

But Chrome does this for some reason:

[ 1     ] [ 2     ]

[ 3     ] [ 4     ]

This is really annoying, because it often makes the flyout way longer than it needs to be while being half empty horizontally. Opera exhibits the same behavior, while IE/Edge is OK.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what I can do to avoid it?

Thanks :-)

```
<ul>
  <li>1<br>...</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4<br>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing this with columns and not with, let's say, flexbox?

Comment: It needs to be backward compatible with older browsers that do not support flexbox.